# How to deal with functional tests depending on information sent by e-mail?

Tags: authentication, functional-testing

I was writing functional tests while implementing a "Reset my password" feature but I got stuck with the reset token as an crucial dependency.

The token represents a dependency and is breaking the test's automation aspect.

Any ideas on how to solve the token dependency?

Comment: You may have to mock or otherwise simulate the act of sending a real email.

Comment: Something I'd like to avoid is doing something exclusively for the test environmet, such as printing the token in order to make the tests more practical.

Comment: There's no way to get around having some code that's exclusive to your tests (after all, the test itself is some code that's only used for testing).  But it probably doesn't take that much code to mock your token requirement.  All you have to do is make a `MockToken` class (or something like that) that pretends to be a valid reset token.  In a lot of cases, all that involves is simply returning `true` from a method that would do so some complicated parsing and logic in your real non-test code.

Comment: Seconding Ben's comment, sometimes you have to make some changes to the mainline code in order to facilitate testing.  The way I see it; testing is important enough to justify this.